# How is number of photons found on a spectra?

Tags: nuclear-physics, spectroscopy, data-analysis, particle-detectors

Sorry for the stupid question, but I am very new to this and have no background in physics. Say we have a spectra as the one in the image, which represent a charge distribution over a specific channel, and represents one single event (please correct me if I am wrong). Can the number of photons be found from there? Is it the area under the curve? Could please suggest me some material to read about this, I would need to analyze those data but I have not taken advanced physics classes yet. Thanks a lot.

[image: Example graph]

Comment: Without your source is hard to say. But it would stand to reason if you added up all the things listed as counts then you would get all the counts. This is the same as area under the curve. Just handle the log scale correctly

Comment: You have counts vs channels. Admittedly you don’t know the detector efficiency, any windows set on the multichannel analyzer, or pileup issues, but you have what events were counted.

Comment: I just took this image from google actually, but the plots I get are actually very similar

Answer (score 0):

Your plot says "counts" but as you do not give a link to the detector it is not clear whether it is pulses of light that are counted or individual hits of photons.

In general, if you have a plot where the energy of the beam can be integrated, and it is a single frequency beam of light the number of photons can be estimated by dividing the energy by the energy of each photon $h*ν$  where $ν$ is the frequency of the light and [h Planck's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant).

This would work with [laser pulses](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jfxFD9cJfo) since they are single frequency.

If there are many frequencies but you know the energy in the plot, you would need the spectrum of frequencies to use it to estimate an average number of photons.

search number "of photons in a pulse  video" to get links.

Comment: I think it's an indivual hit, as there is a radioactive source in the middle and the data are recorded when an "event" happens. Does it change something?

Comment: you should know if you are counting photons or other radiation.   The  comment to your question  by  @shai  holds in this case.